# Generate requirements.txt from pyproject.toml

Tags: docker, python-poetry

I'm using poetry in my project and now working on a feature that will allow to run the app inside of a docker container. Now, my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
COPY pyproject.toml /
...
RUN poetry install
```

The last command takes around 4 minutes which is quite a lot so I thought of caching somehow this dependencies. I'm trying to convert my pyproject.toml to requirements.txt so I could feed it to Docker and it would cache it if the file hasn't been changed since the last run.

Now I'm trying:

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt
```

And it only writes dependencies from [tool.poetry.dependencies] section, but the problem is that I have other sections and would like to see dependencies from those in my requirements.txt file. How should I modify the command above so it would take dependencies from other sections as well.

P.S. Maybe you might know other ways of how to cache poetry install in docker, I'd really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do 2-step dependencies install with poetry to cache dependensies like in example here - https://pythonspeed.com/articles/poetry-vs-docker-caching/, no need to migrate to requirements.txt. The idea is to copy only toml, install dependencies (this way dependencies will cache and need to update only if toml changes), then copy you source files (which change more often, than toml) and do install again. More detailed explanation in the link above (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/poetry-vs-docker-caching/)